# About memory leak in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I am working on loading images from document directory using `SDWEBImage` and showing on `UICollectionView`.

I it keep's crashing by saying you "`Received memory warning`" . So if anybody knows the better solution to load images from document directory please help.
Thank you.

This is my memory usage and leak issue

[image]

To load images using `SDWebImage` i am using the below code

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
[cell.imgViewForCategory sd_setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"] options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly];
```

here `imagePath` is the my `Document Directory` path of my Image.

Comment: How did you load images from document? How is your code?

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: How big is your image?

Comment: I am having lot of images stored In my document directory may be 500 or more and I am fetching more images from there with each image is max 2 MB in size.

Comment: Did you use `for` loop to get them one time?

Comment: yes I have used for loop for getting the images

Comment: @Pradumna, save the image path in local db (core data or sqlite) while you saving the image. Then retrieve all the image path with query in the collection VC, so that no need of for loop. The memory issue is arising due to heavy looping.

Comment: Is there any third party is available to load images from document directory asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use AutoReleasePool to avoid memory leak.

```
for (NSString *imageName in names) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithName:imageName];
    }
}
```

Comment: no it is not working as i am loading these images in collection view while scrolling the collection it crash by saying "Received memory warning"

Comment: ARC already handle auto release so `@autoreleasepool` don't have any effect here i suppose, the problem lying in somewhere else

Comment: @Tj3n But this trick can avoid memory peak according to http://www.apress.com/9781430241164